# how to autoselect same values from two arrays

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Have two arrays one have all values of another array..how to autoselect same values contains by both arrays using foreach loop

```php
<?php foreach ($stores as $key => $value) { ?>
   <?php foreach ($store_name as $key => $name) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" <?php  echo  $name['id'] == $value['id'] ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $value['store_name']; ?></option>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: first of all at a time only one value can be selected in drop-down.So your question is unclear now that what you are trying to do. Please explain more about your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use in_array function to check if a value is present in another array or not. the code should be like following,

```
<?php 
     $store_ids = array_column($store_name, 'id'); // get only id values from second array
     foreach ($stores as $key => $value) { 
?>
<option value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" <?php  echo in_array($value['id'],$store_ids ) ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo $value['store_name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Also, please make sure you've added `multiple` attribute in your `select` tag.

Comment: Working Great..Thanks for your response

Comment: @JitendraKumar nice to hear that it worked. If so, can you please mark this answer as the accepted one?

Comment: @Shattique okay

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through one, and check to see if that value exists in the other:

```
<?php

$fruits =
[
    'apple',
    'banana',
    'sultana'
];

$picks =
[
    'apple',
    'sultana'
];

foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
    echo in_array($fruit, $picks)
        ? "$fruit SELECTED\n"
        : "$fruit\n";
}
```

Output:

```
apple SELECTED
banana
sultana SELECTED
```